# How to prove that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{XY}(x,y)dxdy=1$?

Tags: probability-theory

> Suppose $f_{XY}$ is the joint density of two random variables $X$ and $Y$. How to prove that $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{XY}(x,y)\ dxdy=1?$$

Comment: This is true by definition of probability distribution functions (see e.g. [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_probability_distribution#Continuous_case)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$Definition:$ 
Two random variables $X$ and $Y$ are jointly continuous if there exists a nonnegative function $f_{XY}:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, such that, for any set $A\in \mathbb{R}^2$, we have
\begin{align}\label{eq:double-int}
  P\big((X,Y) \in A\big) =\iint \limits_A f_{XY}(x,y)dxdy \hspace{30pt} *
\end{align}
The function $f_{XY}(x,y)$ is called the joint probability density function (PDF) of $X$ and $Y$.

In the above definition, the domain of $f_{XY}(x,y)$ is the entire $\mathbb{R}^2$. We may define the range of $(X,Y)$ as

\begin{align}%\label{}
\nonumber  R_{XY}=\{(x,y) | f_{X,Y}(x,y)>0\}.
\end{align}

The above double integral (Equation $*$) exists for all sets $A$ of practical interest. If we choose $A=\mathbb{R}^2$, then the probability of $(X,Y)∈A$ must be one, so we must have
\begin{align}%\label{}
\nonumber  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{XY}(x,y)dxdy=1
\end{align}
The intuition behind the joint density $f_{XY}(x,y)$ is similar to that of the PDF of a single random variable.

Answer (score 1):

We know that

\begin{align}%\label{}
\nonumber  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{XY}(x,y)dxdy=\nonumber  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  f_{X}(x)dx
\end{align}

We also know that

\begin{align}%\label{}
\nonumber  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  f_{X}(x)dx=1
\end{align}
Hope you understand this.

Comment: Thanks, but I need proof not fact.

Comment: Do you need proof of first equation which states that if you sum over a random variable in its joint pdf, it vanishes or second equation which states that sum of all probabilities is 1?